# Special characters in R code output not printed into PDF (though graphical stuff works well)

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, rstudio

**WORKING EXAMPLE IN THE END**

I want to use knitr to have R code inside LaTeX document, but it doesn't print correctly into PDF when there are non-ascii characters. The situation is similar as in the question user **unikum** asked in [GitHub](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/436), but the solution given there helped only partially in my case.

Ideally the printed line(s) would be inside normal text and have suitable LaTeX formatting, especially in cases where the result is simply one line. I have some uses in my mind where example sentences in a research paper would be automatically taken from the data files.

I wrote Rnw file in RStudio (0.98.945), I used XeLaTex for typesetting. I created PDF simply by clicking **Compile PDF** button in RStudio. I have MacBook Pro with Mavericks. Please let me know if some additional information is needed. I can also switch to other programs (like TeXShop etc.) if that helps.

I'm still learning all these tools, R, knitr and LaTeX, so I apologise if I have missed any obvious solution or misuse some terminology. I tried to combine different solutions from similar problems, like this about [Polish characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666537/special-characters-in-knitr-cairodevice-doesnt-work) or this about [Hebrew](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/527). There are many people writing about bit similar problems, but I still have problems to get it together. I guess this is encoding issue.

Here is my LaTeX preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\setromanfont{Charis SIL}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
options(device = function(file, width = 7, height = 7, ...) {
cairo_pdf(tempfile(), width = width, height = height, ...)
})
@
```

In normal text I can have any possible unicode characters and they appear all correctly in the pdf: мичаа лыддьыны позьӧ, me t'š́uži š́urs e̮kmis-š́o dasɛ͔d voɛ͔ š́ent'a·b das-e̮kmi͔sɛ͔d lunɛ.

I assume this has something to do with encoding.

In my example I scan to R the text file (test.txt) that contains following 10 lines, they are just random word forms in Finnish and Komi:

```
Серафимлӧн
тшӧктісны
налысь
sivulla
ёрт
дугдыны
sivu-ovi
Esko
Серафим
akkuna
```

The following code prints the result correctly:

```
<<test1, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
test <- scan(file="test.txt", what="char", sep="\n")
wordlat <- grep("sivu", test, value=T)
print(wordlat)
@
```

The result is this:

```
[1] "sivulla"  "sivu-ovi"
```

But this doesn't:

```
<<test2, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
test <- scan(file="test.txt", what="char", sep="\n")
wordcyr <- grep("Серафим", test, value=T)
print(wordcyr)
@
```

What comes out is:

```
[1] "" ""
```

I modified marginally the example which was posted to [GitHub](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/436). I just wanted to have both latin and cyrillic in the labels. As one could expect, adding cairo_pdf to the beginning helped:

```
<<pie-plot, dev='cairo_pdf'>>=
x <- gl(3, 4, 50, labels=c("Pretty easy!", "Дзик гӧгӧрвотӧм!", "Кувны позьӧ :("))
pie(table(x), main="How difficult is this question")
@
```

The pie comes out perfectly, but there is clearly still something wrong, because the code above it says:

```
x<-gl(3,4,50,labels=c("Pretty easy!"," !","  :("))pie(table(x),main="How difficult is this question")
```

WORKING EXAMPLE:

I see now that I should had paid more attention to give a piece of code one can just copy and run. My apologies for that. So the example below is the same as in my original post, but it can be copied into RStudio and it should make one page PDF which has the problems I described. Sorry for repeating the same, but I though it maybe makes my question more unclear if I start to edit the whole post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\setromanfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
options(device = function(file, width = 7, height = 7, ...) {
cairo_pdf(tempfile(), width = width, height = height, ...)
})
@

So this comes out fine.

<<test1, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
test1 <- c("Серафимлӧн", "тшӧктісны", "налысь", "sivulla", "ёрт", "дугдыны", "sivu-ovi", "Esko", "Серафим", "akkuna")
wordlat <- grep("sivu", test1, value=T)
print(wordlat)
@

But for some reason this doesn't. How to make it show characters correctly, that's the whole question I posted about.

<<test2, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
test2 <- c("Серафимлӧн", "тшӧктісны", "налысь", "sivulla", "ёрт", "дугдыны", "sivu-ovi", "Esko", "Серафим", "akkuna")
wordcyr <- grep("Сера", test2, value=T)
print(wordcyr)
@

The graphical things come out fine with cairo-package, but only within the graph itself:

<<pie-plot, dev='cairo_pdf'>>=
x <- gl(3, 4, 50, labels=c("Pretty easy!", "Дзик гӧгӧрвотӧм!", "Кувны позьӧ :("))
pie(table(x), main="How difficult is this question")
@

The code above the graph in the PDF has the same problem as in earlier example which contained cyrillic:

c("Pretty easy!"," !","  :("))

\end{document}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorry. I don't get your point. Could you please post ONE minimal working example (MWE), so I am able to reproduce the code on my machine? Would make it easier for me to help.

Comment: I added a working example! Just let me know if something is still unclear!

Comment: I haven't fully solved this problem yet, but I've understood it seems to be just a font issue. The standard font for code chunks in lots of this knitr - LaTeX - PDF stuff doesn't contain very much non-Latin characters. When working with Rmd it is easy to change the fonts in YAML, i.e. sansfont: Calibri Light, monofont: Ubuntu Mono. Also there the pie plot above needs settings like: ```{r, dev='CairoPDF', warning=F} in order to work well. So the question seems to boil down into how effectively tell LaTeX and knitr which fonts to use in code chunk output.

Comment: @nikopartanen did you find a fix to this? Have you tried setting the `encoding`? I remember encountering a similar problem, not sure it applies to your case: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/postscript.html

Comment: I think the issue was essentially that (at least back in 2014) the font used by default in those contexts didn't support all characters I had there, and setting the font to something which covers everything fixes the problem. Thanks for the link, setting the font from there can certainly help in solving this problem as well.